# Controlling network link conditioner from app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, networking

I have to evaluate our app on iphone in a bunch of network conditions (15 of them). 
This I need to do in different locations (office/basement/while driving etc.) and for different operations within the app.

As you can see the number of combinations blow up and it'll be very difficult to test all of this out by manually changing the network condition, triggering app operation etc.

Will it be possible to simulate network behaviours (just like NLC does) from within the app itself?

Like when I start the experiment in office, network condition 1 is set automatically via code, app operation too is triggered automatically.
Then wait for 2-5 minutes, set network condition 2 automatically, app operation trigger.

And so on...

Comment: The whole point of the link conditioner is to allow you to simulate different network conditions.  There should be no need to change your physical location at the same time. Doing so is doubling up on what the link conditioner already does

Comment: You find choppy networks in lift/basement or while you are driving and go into a tunnel. It's difficult to simulate changing network conditions in NLC. That's why we want to introduce the location variable as well.

Comment: Even if do manage to get rid of the location variable, the number of  app operations means enough combinations are there for us to seriously consider simulating network conditions from within app as I asked above.

Comment: Ok, well I don't believe that it is possible

Comment: Well I think the broader question is if it is possible to simulate network conditions from an app, not necessarily simulate NLC.